# Is -1 one character or two characters in INT column

Tags: sql, mysql

Assume this table

```
`publish` INT( 1 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT  '0'
```

Can -1, to -9 be entered in this column?

Comment: What happens when you test it?

Comment: @Vincent it seems StackExchange forums make people lazy (including myself :-)

Comment: @Vincent: I don't have access to a mysql database right now, and I need to churn out some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  The number in parentheses is just the display width:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

In particular:

> MySQL supports an extension for
>   optionally specifying the display
>   width of integer data types in
>   parentheses following the base keyword
>   for the type. For example, INT(4)
>   specifies an INT with a display width
>   of four digits. This optional display
>   width may be used by applications to
>   display integer values having a width
>   less than the width specified for the
>   column by left-padding them with
>   spaces. (That is, this width is
>   present in the metadata returned with
>   result sets. Whether it is used or not
>   is up to the application.)
>
> The display width does not constrain
>   the range of values that can be stored
>   in the column. Nor does it prevent
>   values wider than the column display
>   width from being displayed correctly.
>   For example, a column specified as
>   SMALLINT(3) has the usual SMALLINT
>   range of -32768 to 32767, and values
>   outside the range permitted by three
>   digits are displayed in full using
>   more than three digits.

The type INT supports signed and unsigned integers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes int(1) can store -1 to -9. In Mysql, parentheses following the base keyword for the type  is used only for padding 0 if the width of dispayed number is less than what is specified in the paranthesis.For ex, on using int(3) , 1 will be dispayed as 001.And if the number is greater than given width , the number is dispayed completely.For example,for int(3) , 1234 will be dispayed as complete 1234.The width in paranthesis doesnt effect the actual range that can be stored.